# How to force remove records form lines in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

something wrong happened in account moves as adding an analytic account to journal items of vendor bills and I need to loop on all lines in account moves and remove the analytic account from all lines by this bit of code

```
class NewModule(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.move'

def analytic(self):
    all=self.env['account.move'].search([('type','=','in_invoice')])
    ana=all.line_ids.mapped('analytic_account_id')
    ana.unlink()
```

but when this method run I get this error **"The operation cannot be completed: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.
Model: Analytic Line (account.analytic.line), Constraint: account_analytic_line_account_id_fkey"** as image below 
[image]

otherwise if tried to remove the analytic account for UI it removed without any issues but there is too many bills to do it manually

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's worked for me with this method

```
def analytic(self):    
self.env['account.move'].search([('type', 'in', ('out_invoice', 'in_invoice'))]).line_ids.write({'analytic_account_id':[(5, 0, 0)]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to delete analytic_account objects.
You need to remove Many2Many connections to the analytic_account objects.

```py
all=self.env['account.move'].search([('type','=','in_invoice')])
all.write({'analytic_account_id':[(5, 0, 0)]})
```

It should be like that. But I did not test it.